# Adding two DATA sql queries into one

Tags: sql, sas, query-builder, enterprise-guide

I have the following data set:

Need to add two new columns
- First one subtracts row 1 from row 2 for each customer, so that we can have the # of "Days" after which a customer renew's their membership
- Second one calculates the # of times the customer renewed their membership which would be just a count starting from 0.

```
Row   - Customer    - Renew Date   - Type of Renewal  - Days_Since  -Prev_Renewal
 1       - A        - June 10, 2010        - X                        
 2       - A        - May 01, 2011         - Y  
 3       - B        - Jan 05, 2010         - Y  
 4       - B        - Dec 10, 2010         - Z   
 5       - B        - Dec 10, 2011         - X
```

Here is the code that I am using right now. Is there a way to combine these two set of queries into one ?

```
data have;
informat renew_date ANYDTDTE.;
format renew_date DATE9.;
infile datalines dlm='-';
input Row Customer $ Renew_Date  Renewal_Type $;
datalines;
 1       - A        - June 10, 2010        - X                        
 2       - A        - May 01, 2011         - Y  
 3       - B        - Jan 05, 2010         - Y  
 4       - B        - Dec 10, 2010         - Z   
 5       - B        - Dec 10, 2011         - X    
 ;;;;
 run;

 data want;
 set have;
 by customer;
 retain prev_days;  *retain the value of prev_days from one row to the next;
 if first.customer 
 then 
    days_since=0; 
    *initialize days_since to zero for each customer's first record;
 else days_since=renew_date-prev_days; *otherwise set it to the difference;
 output;    *output the current record;
 prev_days=renew_date; 
 *now change prev_days to the renewal date so the next record has it;
 run;
```

---

```
data want1;  
 set have;  
by customer;   
retain prev_renewal;   
if first.customer then prev_renewal=0;   
else prev_renewal=prev_renewal+1;   
output;   
run;
```

Thanks

Comment: Suggest you add a tag to indicate what dialect of sql and/or what platform you are using.

Comment: That does not appear to be SQL

Comment: using enterprise guide

Answer (score 0):

This is not SQL but data step / Base SAS code - the proprietary (4GL) language of SAS Institute, which actually pre-dates SQL.

Regarding your program - it's worth pointing out that the data must be sorted or indexed (by customer in this case) before the BY statement can be used.  In this case your datalines were in the right order.

Here is the combined code you need:

```
data want (drop=prev_days);
   set have;
   by customer;
   retain prev_days; 
   if first.customer then do;
      days_since=0; 
      prev_renewal=0;
   end;
   else do;
      days_since=renew_date-prev_days;
      prev_renewal+1; /* IMPLIED retain - special syntax */
   end;
   output;
   prev_days=renew_date;
run;
```